# Instanciate object in parent with parameters

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to make a simple list editor in Dart, with Polymer, but I have some problems.

I will start by showing a screenshot of what it will look like.
[design of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLKbK.png)

The left drawer is filled dynamically at run-time (a rest api is used to get the items). 
The items are "MLayers" and clicking the button should add the corresponding "Layer" to the right part of the app.

The thing is I can't find a way to do this! I tried to launch a customEvent when the button is clicked but the method responsible of adding the new layer need the layer name (and I can't find a way to add parameters to customEvents...).

What do you recommand?

The structure of the app is:

mainApp

_ Drawer

__ MLayer

__ Layer

I think the class responsible of adding Layers should be the Drawer (in fact it contain the drawer AND the content). The Layer constructor should use the name (or ID) of the MLayer to display corresponding properties (lets say the MLayer "Dense" has properties "name" and "size"; the Layer is in fact an instance, while the MLayer is the maquette).

Thanks for the read!

EDIT: as requested, [here's the code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c97f6b8f9c2f8d057914bccc7c7d6210)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some code to the question that demonstates what you have tried and where you failed. To me it's not clear what your question is about.

Comment: The question is not about code not working but what should I code. To clarify, I want a child element (a list item) to instanciate an item inside another list (based on the parameters of the first list item). You really need to look at the image to understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Please check the help menu about what questions to ask or not to ask and how to ask good questions. Your question should demonstrate your effort, what you try to accomplish and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I didn't find the right way to do it, so I simply broke encapsulation by adding a property "MLayerDrawer" to my "MLayer" object and calling its method...

I'm still open to suggestions because this clearly isn't the right way to do it, it just work but is really dirty.